# Уровни стилей в HTML и нагрузка на HTTP-сервер от SSI

Tags: http, html, ssi, css

Прохожу онлайн тест от института. На некоторые вопросы ответа не могу найти.

- **Число уровней каскадных стилей в HTML?**
- **Где выполняются CGI-скрипты?**
- **Где выполняются SSI-команды?**
- **При использовании SSI увеличится ли нагрузка на HTTP сервер?**

На 2 и 3 вроде бы знаю ответ, но не уверен: вроде оба на вебсервере выполняются?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Наверно, имеется ввиду h1-h6. Поэтому ответ - 6.
2. Да, на сервере.
3. На сервере. На то они **S**erver **S**ide **I**nclude.
4. При неправильном подходе - да, конечно. В любом случае, серверу приходиться компоновать страницу.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Так что на 4-й ответить, нагрузка не изменится, или увеличится?

Comment: увеличится. Но навряд ли уменьшиться.